# ShowcaseView with gestures

Tags: android, gestures, showcaseview

I'm using the great [ShowcaseView library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) in my project. Along with that I'm also using this awesome wrapper class [ShowcaseViewExample](http://novoda.com/blog/blog/Using-the-ShowcaseView) to show the views one after the other.

This works great but I'm lost as to how to use gestures.

Code so far:

```
 public void showcaseMainActivity() {
          views = new ShowcaseViews(this, R.layout.showcase_view_template);
          views.addView(new ShowcaseViews.ItemViewProperties(R.id.some_menu, R.string.showcase_title, R.string.showcase_message, ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_ITEM));
          views.addView(new ShowcaseViews.ViewProperties(R.id.showcaseButton, R.string.showcase_title, R.string.showcase_message));
          views.show();
        }
```

Where do I add the code to use gestures for the `showcaseButton`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not the one to answer your question, I'm more of a fellow user who had to do it in what I suspect is the wrong way.

*So far I've only focused on making the gesture's work. I don't know how to choose the size of the circles*

I wanted to use it the same way you do, but it didn't get me anywhere because I didn't find out where to put the gesture in the line where I added the view. So I did it my way.

Like this:

First I defined the showcaseview:

```
Fragment thisFrag;
ShowcaseView sv;
ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions co;
```

And in my oncreate I have this:

```
co = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
thisFrag = this;
```

Then I called this function when I wanted the showcase to be viewed:

```
public static void showShowcase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    co.hideOnClickOutside = false;
    co.showcaseId = 1;
    sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(R.id.scrollView1, thisFrag.getActivity(), "Some funny text", " Smaller and funnier text ", co);
    sv.animateGesture(200, 500, 200, 0);

    OnShowcaseEventListener OSEvListner = new OnShowcaseEventListener() {
        public void onShowcaseViewHide(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
            switch (co.showcaseId) {
            case 1:
                co.showcaseId = 2;
                sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(R.id.scrollView2, thisFrag.getActivity(), "How to scroll down", " ", co);
                sv.setOnShowcaseEventListener(this);
                sv.animateGesture(200, 500, 200, 0);
                break;
            case 2:
                co.showcaseId = 3;
                sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(R.id.scrollView3, thisFrag.getActivity(),
                        "Do this to change tabs", "", co);
                sv.setOnShowcaseEventListener(this);
                 sv.animateGesture(200, 500, 500, 500);
                break;
            case 3:
                Main.switchTab(1);
                OtherFragment.showShowcase();
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowcaseViewShow(ShowcaseView showcaseView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    sv.setOnShowcaseEventListener(OSEvListner);


}
```

Hope there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the method `overrideButtonClick` in following sample:**

```
ShowcaseView showcaseView = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(new ViewTarget(yourView), activity, "this is title", "this is detail");

showcaseView.overrideButtonClick(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //your onClick code
                }
});
```